# Need some help adding a music player to my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, mp3, soundcloud

I want to add a music player to a site I am having built. My developer is down to the last finishing touches and he is making it seem like this is going to be very difficult to do (or maybe he just doesn't wanna do it)

I want it to work like these blogs

Hilly Dilly
The Music Ninja
Earmilk

It looks like they all have the same custom soundcloud player. With the functionality that when you navigate to different parts of the site the music will keep playing.

Now my question is this something Some what easy to do and how much would something like this cost to add to a WP Site. I put up a couple ads for hire just looking to get a ball park cost since I am going to need to find another person to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to [integrate a Soundcloud Music Player on WordPress](http://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/soundcloud-audio-player/) site?

- What your looking for has been done

I believe that would require 1-3 hours, perhaps $125 for a clean, wicked player.

1. Find the code online
2. Replicate the results
3. Integrate with your site.